# raise Exception or raise Exception()

Tags: python, exception

I need to raise an exception. In my specific case `NotImplementedError`.
What is the difference between
`Raise NotImplementedError` and `raise NotImplementedError()`.
Which is considered a better practice? Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference between `raise X` and `raise X()`. It's better to use the second form and pass a message like `raise RuntimeError('bad argument')`. If there is no useful message like your case I go with first syntax. It's a matter of taste.

The first form is a remaining of old style raising (not valid in Python3):

```
raise X, 'a'
```

is the same as

```
raise X('a')
```